# Not sync intents are being generate after re-link the smart home action

Tags: actions-on-google

After the oauth process is completed I get a message that says "Couldn't update the settings check connectivity" and I do not receive a post to my API with a sycn intent. I also tried request sync  from [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create-app#request-sync) using my key and projectId and I keep receiving error 400 status.

How could I test my sync request or see some logs and how could I make the request sync for test work?

I am sending the exact request is in the documentation but with my parameters

[image]

Log ADM:

```
10-24 14:12:59.031: W/ls(29731): type=1400 audit(0.0:1789): avc: denied { getattr } for uid=2000 path="/init" dev="rootfs" ino=10842 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:init_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:12:59.214: W/ls(29739): type=1400 audit(0.0:1790): avc: denied { getattr } for uid=2000 path="/data/tombstones" dev="dm-1" ino=46 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tombstone_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
10-24 14:13:00.454: W/CastSocket(2541): [controller-0142 API] SSL DidCallSslEngineBeginHandshake: false
10-24 14:13:00.509: E/HomeApp|af(29649): Empty HGS device ID field
10-24 14:13:00.509: E/HomeApp|af(29649): Empty HGS device ID field
10-24 14:13:00.509: E/HomeApp|af(29649): Empty HGS device ID field
10-24 14:13:00.509: E/HomeApp|af(29649): Empty HGS device ID field
10-24 14:13:00.509: E/HomeApp|af(29649): Empty HGS device ID field
10-24 14:13:01.881: W/HomeApp|BrowseFragment(29649): Couldn't unregister receiver
10-24 14:13:01.986: W/HomeApp|BrowseFragment(29649): Couldn't unregister receiver
10-24 14:13:02.041: E/cnss-daemon(705): Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 16
10-24 14:13:02.053: W/Utils(2561): Show action bar
10-24 14:13:02.118: W/CronetHttpEngine(2561): Upload request without a content type.
10-24 14:13:02.118: W/CronetHttpEngine(2561): Upload request without a content type.
10-24 14:13:02.594: W/SurfaceFlinger(518): couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
10-24 14:13:03.956: W/DiscoveryManager(2541): BroadcastReceiver is already registered
10-24 14:13:03.968: W/MdnsClient_Cast(2541): Multicast lock held. Releasing. Subtypes:"%9E5E7C8F47989526C9BCD95D24084F6F0B27C5ED,CC1AD845"
10-24 14:13:03.972: W/MdnsClient_Cast(2541): #acquireLock. Multicast lock not held. Acquiring. Subtypes:"%9E5E7C8F47989526C9BCD95D24084F6F0B27C5ED"
10-24 14:13:04.044: W/ls(29761): type=1400 audit(0.0:1791): avc: denied { getattr } for uid=2000 path="/init" dev="rootfs" ino=10842 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:init_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:04.224: W/ls(29767): type=1400 audit(0.0:1792): avc: denied { getattr } for uid=2000 path="/data/tombstones" dev="dm-1" ino=46 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tombstone_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
10-24 14:13:04.978: W/CronetHttpEngine(2561): Upload request without a content type.
10-24 14:13:05.435: W/SurfaceFlinger(518): couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
10-24 14:13:06.540: E/WifiHAL(1510): fetchLowiCbTableAndCapabilities: NULL lowi_handle, err: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/liblowi_wifihal.so" not found
10-24 14:13:06.540: E/WifiHAL(1510): getLowiCallbackTable: LOWI is not supported.
10-24 14:13:06.541: E/WifiHAL(1510): fetchLowiCbTableAndCapabilities: NULL lowi_handle, err: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/liblowi_wifihal.so" not found
10-24 14:13:06.541: E/WifiHAL(1510): getLowiCallbackTable: LOWI is not supported.
10-24 14:13:06.545: E/WifiHAL(1510): fetchLowiCbTableAndCapabilities: NULL lowi_handle, err: dlopen failed: library "/vendor/lib/liblowi_wifihal.so" not found
10-24 14:13:06.545: E/WifiHAL(1510): getLowiCallbackTable: LOWI is not supported.
10-24 14:13:08.387: W/QCNEJ(1951): |CORE| CNE received unexpected action: android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
10-24 14:13:09.037: W/ls(29775): type=1400 audit(0.0:1793): avc: denied { getattr } for uid=2000 path="/init" dev="rootfs" ino=10842 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:init_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:09.247: W/ls(29784): type=1400 audit(0.0:1794): avc: denied { getattr } for uid=2000 path="/data/tombstones" dev="dm-1" ino=46 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tombstone_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
10-24 14:13:10.623: W/DynamiteModule(29791): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
10-24 14:13:10.639: W/System(29791): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
10-24 14:13:10.656: W/System(29791): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000011/n/armeabi-v7a
10-24 14:13:10.656: W/System(29791): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000011/n/armeabi
10-24 14:13:10.786: W/ActivityManager(1510): Activity is launching as a new task, so cancelling activity result.
10-24 14:13:10.945: W/cr_ChildProcLH(29791): Create a new ChildConnectionAllocator with package name = com.android.chrome, sandboxed = true
10-24 14:13:10.964: W/cr_tabmodel(29791): Starting to fetch tab list.
10-24 14:13:10.964: E/cr_tabmodel(29791): State file does not exist.
10-24 14:13:11.001: W/dboxed_process0(29816): type=1400 audit(0.0:1795): avc: denied { getattr } for uid=99022 path="/data/data/com.android.chrome" dev="dm-1" ino=1115 scontext=u:r:isolated_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
10-24 14:13:11.011: W/dboxed_process0(29816): type=1400 audit(0.0:1796): avc: denied { search } for uid=99022 name="tmp" dev="dm-1" ino=38 scontext=u:r:isolated_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:shell_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
10-24 14:13:11.071: W/RenderThread(29829): type=1400 audit(0.0:1797): avc: denied { read } for uid=10076 name="gpuclk" dev="sysfs" ino=20909 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:11.075: W/Adreno-ES20(29791): <get_gpu_clk:229>: open failed: errno 13
10-24 14:13:11.099: W/SurfaceFlinger(518): couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
10-24 14:13:11.645: W/cr_KnoxSettingsProvider(29791): Permission to read device policy denied.
10-24 14:13:11.667: W/CrGpuMain(29865): type=1400 audit(0.0:1798): avc: denied { read } for uid=10076 name="gpuclk" dev="sysfs" ino=20909 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:11.664: E/libEGL(29849): validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
10-24 14:13:11.673: W/Adreno-ES20(29849): <get_gpu_clk:229>: open failed: errno 13
10-24 14:13:11.824: W/VideoCapabilities(29849): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
10-24 14:13:11.824: W/VideoCapabilities(29849): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
10-24 14:13:11.828: W/VideoCapabilities(29849): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
10-24 14:13:11.828: W/VideoCapabilities(29849): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
10-24 14:13:11.832: W/VideoCapabilities(29849): Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
10-24 14:13:11.832: W/VideoCapabilities(29849): Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
10-24 14:13:11.994: W/CrGpuMain(29865): type=1400 audit(0.0:1799): avc: denied { read } for uid=10076 name="gpuclk" dev="sysfs" ino=20909 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:12.000: W/Adreno-ES20(29849): <get_gpu_clk:229>: open failed: errno 13
10-24 14:13:12.014: W/CrGpuMain(29865): type=1400 audit(0.0:1800): avc: denied { read } for uid=10076 name="reset_count" dev="sysfs" ino=20921 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:12.014: W/CrGpuMain(29865): type=1400 audit(0.0:1801): avc: denied { read } for uid=10076 name="reset_count" dev="sysfs" ino=20921 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:12.017: W/CrGpuMain(29865): type=1400 audit(0.0:1802): avc: denied { read } for uid=10076 name="reset_count" dev="sysfs" ino=20921 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:12.019: W/Adreno-ES20(29849): <rb_perfcounter_gpu_disjoint_status:487>: open failed: errno 13
10-24 14:13:12.019: W/Adreno-ES20(29849): <rb_perfcounter_gpu_disjoint_status:487>: open failed: errno 13
10-24 14:13:12.022: W/Adreno-ES20(29849): <rb_perfcounter_gpu_disjoint_status:487>: open failed: errno 13
10-24 14:13:12.057: W/Adreno-ES20(29849): <rb_perfcounter_gpu_disjoint_status:487>: open failed: errno 13
10-24 14:13:12.057: W/Adreno-ES20(29849): <rb_perfcounter_gpu_disjoint_status:487>: open failed: errno 13
10-24 14:13:12.054: W/CrGpuMain(29865): type=1400 audit(0.0:1803): avc: denied { read } for uid=10076 name="reset_count" dev="sysfs" ino=20921 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:12.054: W/CrGpuMain(29865): type=1400 audit(0.0:1804): avc: denied { read } for uid=10076 name="reset_count" dev="sysfs" ino=20921 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:12.054: W/CrGpuMain(29865): type=1400 audit(0.0:1805): avc: denied { read } for uid=10076 name="reset_count" dev="sysfs" ino=20921 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:12.060: W/Adreno-ES20(29849): <rb_perfcounter_gpu_disjoint_status:487>: open failed: errno 13
10-24 14:13:12.081: W/CrGpuMain(29865): type=1400 audit(0.0:1806): avc: denied { read } for uid=10076 name="reset_count" dev="sysfs" ino=20921 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:12.081: W/CrGpuMain(29865): type=1400 audit(0.0:1807): avc: denied { read } for uid=10076 name="reset_count" dev="sysfs" ino=20921 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:12.081: W/CrGpuMain(29865): type=1400 audit(0.0:1808): avc: denied { read } for uid=10076 name="reset_count" dev="sysfs" ino=20921 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:12.084: W/Adreno-ES20(29849): <rb_perfcounter_gpu_disjoint_status:487>: open failed: errno 13
10-24 14:13:12.084: W/Adreno-ES20(29849): <rb_perfcounter_gpu_disjoint_status:487>: open failed: errno 13
10-24 14:13:12.087: W/Adreno-ES20(29849): <rb_perfcounter_gpu_disjoint_status:487>: open failed: errno 13
10-24 14:13:12.107: W/System(29891): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/GooglePartnerSetup/lib/arm
10-24 14:13:12.107: W/System(29891): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /oem/lib
10-24 14:13:13.115: W/QCNEJ(1951): |CORE| CNE received unexpected action: android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
10-24 14:13:14.041: W/ls(29911): type=1400 audit(0.0:1809): avc: denied { getattr } for uid=2000 path="/init" dev="rootfs" ino=10842 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:init_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:14.244: W/ls(29917): type=1400 audit(0.0:1810): avc: denied { getattr } for uid=2000 path="/data/tombstones" dev="dm-1" ino=46 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tombstone_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
10-24 14:13:14.873: W/System(29926): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PartnerBookmarksProvider/lib/arm
10-24 14:13:14.873: W/System(29926): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /oem/lib
10-24 14:13:15.047: E/bt_btm(2274): btm_ble_start_scan extended scan
10-24 14:13:15.047: E/bt_btm(2274): btm_ble_start_scan extended scan
10-24 14:13:15.329: W/AppIndexApi(2313): Received an invalid action.
10-24 14:13:15.329: W/Icing(2313): Ignoring usage report, got bad usage info: Uri too long (max 256)
10-24 14:13:15.457: E/PartnerBookmarksReader(29791): ATTENTION: not using partner bookmarks as none were provided
10-24 14:13:15.567: W/chromium(29791): [WARNING:syncer_proto_util.cc(338)] Error posting from syncer: Response Code (bogus on error): -1 Content-Length (bogus on error): -1 Server Status: SYNC_AUTH_ERROR
10-24 14:13:16.459: E/WifiHAL(1510): Received fatal event, sending alert
10-24 14:13:16.521: W/WifiStateMachin(1713): type=1400 audit(0.0:1811): avc: denied { syslog_read } for uid=1000 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
10-24 14:13:18.518: E/cnss-daemon(705): Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 4
10-24 14:13:19.037: W/ls(29964): type=1400 audit(0.0:1812): avc: denied { getattr } for uid=2000 path="/init" dev="rootfs" ino=10842 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:init_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:19.244: W/ls(29975): type=1400 audit(0.0:1813): avc: denied { getattr } for uid=2000 path="/data/tombstones" dev="dm-1" ino=46 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tombstone_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
10-24 14:13:21.866: W/Adreno-ES20(29849): <rb_perfcounter_gpu_disjoint_status:487>: open failed: errno 13
10-24 14:13:21.866: W/Adreno-ES20(29849): <rb_perfcounter_gpu_disjoint_status:487>: open failed: errno 13
10-24 14:13:21.870: W/Adreno-ES20(29849): <rb_perfcounter_gpu_disjoint_status:487>: open failed: errno 13
10-24 14:13:21.861: W/CrGpuMain(29865): type=1400 audit(0.0:1814): avc: denied { read } for uid=10076 name="reset_count" dev="sysfs" ino=20921 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:21.861: W/CrGpuMain(29865): type=1400 audit(0.0:1815): avc: denied { read } for uid=10076 name="reset_count" dev="sysfs" ino=20921 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:21.864: W/CrGpuMain(29865): type=1400 audit(0.0:1816): avc: denied { read } for uid=10076 name="reset_count" dev="sysfs" ino=20921 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:21.905: W/BrowserControlActivity(2561): Transition animation scale is not available
10-24 14:13:21.951: W/AppIndexApi(2313): Received an invalid action.
10-24 14:13:21.951: W/Icing(2313): Ignoring usage report, got bad usage info: Uri too long (max 256)
10-24 14:13:21.996: W/AppIndexApi(2313): Received an invalid action.
10-24 14:13:21.996: W/Icing(2313): Ignoring usage report, got bad usage info: Uri too long (max 256)
10-24 14:13:22.091: W/InvalidationClientCore(29791): [TiclService] Ticl being stopped: Client: <ApplicationClientIdP: client_type=1018 client_name=f9d0f527-354a-40c1-9569-b94bdf1eb4bd>, \n\006\n\004\010\003\020\001\022\022\t\212\2257T[\230\374\203\021\324O\215\273\312\017\026\205\032\007\010\2272\020\003\030\001, <RunState: 2>
10-24 14:13:22.138: E/Surface(29849): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x969e5cc0
10-24 14:13:22.388: E/cnss-daemon(705): Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 4
10-24 14:13:22.431: W/AppIndexApi(2313): Received an invalid action.
10-24 14:13:22.431: W/Icing(2313): Ignoring usage report, got bad usage info: Uri too long (max 256)
10-24 14:13:22.506: W/AppIndexApi(2313): Received an invalid action.
10-24 14:13:22.506: W/Icing(2313): Ignoring usage report, got bad usage info: Uri too long (max 256)
10-24 14:13:22.826: W/AppIndexApi(2313): Received an invalid action.
10-24 14:13:22.826: W/Icing(2313): Ignoring usage report, got bad usage info: Uri too long (max 256)
10-24 14:13:22.828: W/SurfaceFlinger(518): couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
10-24 14:13:22.828: W/SurfaceFlinger(518): couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
10-24 14:13:23.092: W/CronetHttpEngine(2561): Upload request without a content type.
10-24 14:13:23.398: W/S3NetworkUtils(2561): [Upload] response code: 500
10-24 14:13:23.405: W/ASPrefControlBase(2561): #onFailure
10-24 14:13:23.405: W/ASPrefControlBase(2561): com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.o: errorCode: -83903, engine: 2
10-24 14:13:23.405: W/ASPrefControlBase(2561):  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.t.b(SourceFile:7)
10-24 14:13:23.405: W/ASPrefControlBase(2561):  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.o.a(SourceFile:9)
10-24 14:13:23.405: W/ASPrefControlBase(2561):  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.m.TJ(SourceFile:61)
10-24 14:13:23.405: W/ASPrefControlBase(2561):  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.s3.l.run(SourceFile:19)
10-24 14:13:23.405: W/ASPrefControlBase(2561):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
10-24 14:13:23.405: W/ASPrefControlBase(2561):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-24 14:13:23.405: W/ASPrefControlBase(2561):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
10-24 14:13:23.405: W/ASPrefControlBase(2561):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-24 14:13:23.405: W/ASPrefControlBase(2561):  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.h.run(Unknown Source)
10-24 14:13:23.405: W/ASPrefControlBase(2561):  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ap.run(SourceFile:4)
10-24 14:13:23.405: W/ASPrefControlBase(2561):  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ap.run(SourceFile:4)
10-24 14:13:23.405: W/ASPrefControlBase(2561):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
10-24 14:13:23.405: W/ASPrefControlBase(2561):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
10-24 14:13:23.405: W/ASPrefControlBase(2561):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
10-24 14:13:23.405: W/ASPrefControlBase(2561):  at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.l.run(SourceFile:6)
10-24 14:13:23.420: W/InputMethodManagerService(1510): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@fb83b6c attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@88b4c46
10-24 14:13:23.534: E/cnss-daemon(705): Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 16
10-24 14:13:23.597: W/SurfaceFlinger(518): couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
10-24 14:13:24.031: W/ls(30010): type=1400 audit(0.0:1817): avc: denied { getattr } for uid=2000 path="/init" dev="rootfs" ino=10842 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:init_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:24.207: W/ls(30016): type=1400 audit(0.0:1818): avc: denied { getattr } for uid=2000 path="/data/tombstones" dev="dm-1" ino=46 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tombstone_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
10-24 14:13:25.860: W/InvalidationClientCore(29791): [TiclService] Ticl being stopped: Client: <ApplicationClientIdP: client_type=1018 client_name=f9d0f527-354a-40c1-9569-b94bdf1eb4bd>, \n\006\n\004\010\003\020\001\022\022\t\212\2257T[\230\374\203\021\324O\215\273\312\017\026\205\032\007\010\2272\020\003\030\001, <RunState: 2>
10-24 14:13:28.534: E/cnss-daemon(705): Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 16
10-24 14:13:29.037: W/ls(30029): type=1400 audit(0.0:1819): avc: denied { getattr } for uid=2000 path="/init" dev="rootfs" ino=10842 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:init_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
10-24 14:13:29.234: W/ls(30039): type=1400 audit(0.0:1820): avc: denied { getattr } for uid=2000 path="/data/tombstones" dev="dm-1" ino=46 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:tombstone_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

Comment: So there may be a few issues that are causing this issue:

Is your SYNC response valid? You can use the validation tool: https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/tools/validator/

Is your OAuth implementation working? You can use the OAuth tool mentioned in the docs: https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow

Is your server responding quickly? There may be a timeout issue happening during auth that causes it to fail?

Can you get ADB logs `adb logcat` during this time and share that snippet to see if the app is reporting any errors?

Comment: Yes my OAuth is working I tried and tested with the Google developers tool and is quick. I even created an action without OAuth and tried to link to my account to see if I get the post to my API for syncing but I did not get that.

Comment: Can you get ADB logs with `adb logcat` during this time and share that snippet to see if the app is reporting any errors?

Comment: I added the logs something that I found is that the toast error is not getting log at any message level

Comment: Can you provide your project id? Seems like there's a 500 error at S3NetworkUtils

Comment: ProjectId:kevostaging-183317 thank you

Comment: For what it's worth: I get the same message on productive apps (tuya and tplink). I simply cannot link those devices to Google Home and always get the same error that you got. So I assume it's not you, doing something wrong but more likely a bug on Google's end. The line number are slightly different now (7, 9, 74, 19 instead of 7, 9, 61, 19) but apart from that the stacktrace is the same. Did you ever find a solution or cause for this?